# how to write POJO in hibernate having joins for more than 2 tables

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I am new to hibernate, trying to get information from more than 2 tables using hql, if we pull that information we need to put in a POJO how to do mapping for each column to the information that we get as a result from the query?

Tried using @secondarytable() and @Table but it cannot allow more than 1 secondary table annotation.

So is it that we cannot have join for more than 2 tables in hibernate?

Comment: Can you be more descriptive about this. And also share the code about what you have done.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to use the [`@OneToMany`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html), [`@ManyToOne`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ManyToOne.html), and/or [`@ManyToMany`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/ManyToMany.html) annotations to map relationships between all of the entities in your project.

The oracle documentation for those has some pretty good examples, like this one:

Example 1: One-to-Many association using generics

In Customer class:

```
@OneToMany(cascade=ALL, mappedBy="customer")
public Set<Order> getOrders() { return orders; }
```

In Order class:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="CUST_ID", nullable=false)
public Customer getCustomer() { return customer; }
```

In this example, both `Customer` and `Order` would be classes annotated with `@Entity` and `@Table` that correspond to `CUSTOMER` and `ORDER` tables in your database. Any other columns in those tables would also be mapped in the corresponding entity class. The `@OneToMany`, `@ManyToOne` and `@ManyToMany` are used to map foreign keys between your tables, and allow you to have direct references to parent/child rows/objects directly from your entity instances.

With these annotations, you can map as many foreign key references to other tables as you need.